# Check if a particular file is present in the folder using python

Tags: python, file, directory, path, glob

I would like to check if a file is present in a particular folder and print the output. I have the following files in the path: `./programs/data/my_files`:

```
data.txt
an_123.txt
info.log
an_234.txt
filename.txt
main.py
an_55.txt
```

I would like to check if the files `data.txt, filename.txt, and an_55.txt`is present in the path `./programs/data/my_files`. The output should be the following:

```
Success: data.txt exists
```

What I tried so far?

```
pth = str("./programs/data/my_files/")
filename = ['data.txt', 'filename.txt', 'an_55.txt']

for i in filename:
    if glob.glob(os.path.join(pth)):
       print('Success: ', "NaN_"+i+".xml exists")
    else:
       print('Failure: ', "NaN_"+i+".xml does not exists")
```

This prints success only for the last item in the list, (i,e, an_55.txt), others are failure. How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import os
files = os.listdir("your/path/to/files")
for file in files:
      if file.startswith("data") # you can also check if the item is a file here os.isfile()
            print("success")
```

You can also use
`os.path.exists("path to a file")`

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful

```
from pathlib import Path

my_file = Path("/path/to/file") #add your path lists 

if my_file.is_file():
      print("present")
else:
      print("not present")
```